# Can't remove an automated period

Tags: positioning, punctuation

```
\section{Education}
\cventry{2011 -- 2015}{Honours Physics, H.BSc}{FSU}{Tallahassee, Florida}
\textit{}
```

When this is translated there is a comma space period after florida 
(eg...Florida, .)

I don't want this there but can't solve this problem, which I know is easily solved.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Such behaviour is dependent on your set-up.  Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)
that demonstrates the effect.

Comment: What template is that? There are dozens of CV templates out there. A MWE would e better.

Comment: You say you know the solution is easy. That is a strange thing to say when asking a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is the moderncv class. A minimal working example is therefore

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Smith}

\begin{document}

    \cventry{2011 -- 2015}{Honours Physics, H.BSc}{FSU}{Tallahassee, Florida}
    abc

\end{document}
```

Note that I replaced the `\textit{}` from your code snippet with `abc`, so you can see the effect better. The result of this MWE is

[image: MWE]

You can see that the `a` and the `b` are still part of the entry, while `c` is a new paragraph. This is, because the definition of `\cventry` is

```
\cventry{year}{degree title}{institution}{city}{grade}{description}
```

You only provide the arguments up to `city` and no `grade` or `description`. LaTeX therefore assumes that the next letters are your grade (here: `a`) and description (`b`). As you have `\textit{}` on the next line, this `\textit{}` is recognized as `grade` and printed there. As the output of that is empty, you only see the comma which separates the city from the grade, and the final dot.

If you want to omit values, you need to write empty closed brackets in their place:

```
\cventry{2011 -- 2015}{Honours Physics, H.BSc}{FSU}{Tallahassee, Florida}{}{}
```

With that, the MWE becomes

[image: result]

Now `abc` are all in a new paragraph, and there are no unnecessary commas.